# Logstash: Custom delimiter for multi-line XML logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have XML logs where logs are closed with "=======", e.g.

```
<log>
  <level>DEBUG</level>
  <message>This is debug level</message>
</log>

=======

<log>
  <level>ERROR</level>
  <message>This is error level</message>
</log>

=======
```

Every log can span across multiple lines.

How to parse those logs using logstash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using multiline codec. The delimiter "=======" can be used in pattern like this

```
input {
  file {
    type => "xml"
    path => "/path/to/logs/*.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^======="
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "message", "=======", ""]
  }
  xml {
    force_array => false
    source => "message"
    target => "log"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "message" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    codec => json
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Here the combination of `pattern` and `negate => true` means: if a line does **not** start with "=======" it belongs to the previous event (thus `what => "previous"`). When a line with the delimiter is hit, we start a new event. In the filter the delimiter is simply removed with `gsub` and XML is parsed with xml plugin.